# Inserting data in batches into mysql in sqlalchemy python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, database-migration

I have data to insert a million rows in mysql table through python(sqlalchemy). Right now i am inserting in a linear fashion(one item after another). How Can i insert data in batches(roughly 10,000 at a time)? 
Does inserting in batches reduce the overall inserting time of million items? Could not find any reasonable solutions over the internet.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/faq/performance.html#i-m-inserting-400-000-rows-with-the-orm-and-it-s-really-slow)

Comment: please post the reference

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. What do you mean? Just click on that link - [http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/faq/performance.html#i-m-inserting-400-000-rows-with-the-orm-and-it-s-really-slow](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/faq/performance.html#i-m-inserting-400-000-rows-with-the-orm-and-it-s-really-slow)